# Why doesn't this R code produce the same result? (Convolution vs FFT)

Tags: r, fft, convolution

Why doesn't this produce the same result?

```
x <- runif(10, 0, 1)
y <- runif(10, 0, 1)
convolve(x,y)

f <- fft(fft(x)*fft(y), inverse = TRUE)
f/length(f)  ##not the same as convolve(x,y)....
```

If this is not what the function `convolve` is doing, then what else?

Comment: @MauritsEvers Im not a math guy but ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem

Comment: @DiceboyT Setting `conj = FALSE` does indeed work. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

They're not equivalent because `convolve` has default argument `conj = TRUE`, and `fft` returns a vector of type complex. If we change these the results are indeed the same:

```
all.equal(Re(f) / length(f), convolve(x, y, conj = FALSE))
# TRUE
```